# Configuration to use @Mock and @InjectMocks

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-test

I want to use a mock DAO to unit test the service layer in my spring application. In the DAO, it's seesinoFactory is injected using @Inject.

When the test class is configured with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private MyDao myDaoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl myService;
}
```

The output is just as expected.

When I changed the configuration to using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/ServiceTest-context.xml")
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private MyDao myDaoMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl myService;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

The exception,"No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency", will be thrown if sessionFactory bean is not available in ServiceTest-context.xml.

What I don't understand is MyDao is annotated with @Mock already, why is sessionFactory still needed?

Comment: Remember that the initialisation performed by the Spring runner happens BEFORE the call to `initMocks`.  So the Spring runner won't see that the `MyDao` is actually a mock - it hasn't been instantiated yet; and Spring doesn't understand the `@Mock` annotation, so it doesn't know that there WILL be a mock here.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @David, thank you for the response. After I removed the the annotations `@RunWith` and `@ContextConfiguration`, it then worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

you must use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to initialize these mocks and inject them.

1. `@Mock` creates a mock.
2. `@InjectMocks` creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the `@Mock` or `@Spy` annotations into this instance.

Or Using `Mockito.initMocks(this)` as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("test-app-ctx.xml")
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    TestTarget sut;

    @Mock
    Foo mockFoo;

    @Before
    /* Initialized mocks */
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
         // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a while ago already, but your answer would be helpful to others, thx.